# I am working on a discord.py but my on_member_removed(member) does nothing

Tags: python, discord, bots, member

I have added all the required stuff such as the intents and the gateways but my bot just doesnt react, I put a debug print command so that when someone leaves it prints "bot has detected that "+member.mention+ " has left the server" but no matter what I do it really does nothing.

```
import discord

from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
import asyncio
import logging

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = True
intents.presences = True
intents.members = True

def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        data = file.readlines()
    print(data)
        
    data[line_num] = text
    
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines( data )

    print(data)


def leavechannel(serverid, channel):
    flc = open("leavechannels.txt", "r")
    checker = (flc.read())
    flc.close
    
    x = checker.find(serverid)
    print (x)
    if x >= 0:
        lookup = serverid

        with open("leavechannels.txt") as myFile:
            for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 0):
                if lookup in line:
                    print (serverid +' found at line:', num)
                    linecache= num
        print(linecache)
        replace_line("leavechannels.txt", linecache, "\n"+serverid + " = " + channel)
    else:
        flc = open("leavechannels.txt", 'a+')
        flc.write(+serverid + " = " + channel)
        
        
client = discord.Client()

prefix = "ez!"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print("recognised that "+member.mention+" has left")
    with open("leavechannels.txt") as myFile:
        for item in myFile.split("\n"):
            if member.server.id in item:
                leavechannelcache = item.strip()    
    embedVar= discord.Embed(title= member.mention + " has left :(", description="Come back plox!", color=12151512)
    await discord.Object(id=leavechannelcache).send(embed=embedVar)
    print("Sent message to #CHANNEL")



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith(prefix+'leavechannel'):
        if message.author.guild_permissions.manage_channels or message.author.guild_permissions.administration:
            leavechannelhash = message.content.replace(prefix+'leavechannel ', '')
            print (leavechannelhash)
            await message.channel.send("Server leave channel has been set to "+leavechannelhash)
            leavechannel(str(message.guild.id), str(leavechannelhash))
            
                  
        else:
            await message.channel.send("Sorry, "+message.author+"; You do not have sufficient Permissions to do this.")
            

    
client.run('token')
```

i have ommitted a lot of content as it is unnecessary (mostly just stuff related to help and hello world filler commands) but the main issue at hand is that I have the intents.members and I have activated it in the discord apps panel but even after doing so, it doesnt even give me a DEBUG print when someone leaves the server which obviously points towards something being wrong with its detection of member leaves. Any fixes you can suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code, if you're on dpy 1.5.1, there's a intent update so use this on your code.

```
from discord import Intents
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

intent = Intents().all()

bot = Bot(command_prefix='prefix', intents=intent)

... # Some code under this line
```

And try to use `Intents().all`?
In your case put the intent like this`discord.Client(intents=intent)`

Comment: Try to contact me on discord? `Cedric#4630`